# Thrift vs JMS for Java messaging service

Tags: jms, thrift

Does anyone has a good comparison between the two technologies: Thrift vs JMS, in Java for messaging services? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thrift is serialization/rpc framework whereas JMS is full-featured messaging service, so they don't compare directly.

JMS uses stardart java object serialization for ObjectMessage's. It's much slower than thrift and can't be deserialized without java. However, it's possible to serialize objects with any other framework and send them in the form of BytesMessage. For example, ActiveMQ encourages usage of protocol buffers for this task, but it's possible to use any other framework, like thrift, avro, kryo or smile.

This page might give an insight on speed/serialization size of different technologies: 
http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking
In general, each of modern serialization frameworks has its pros and cons, but they provide approximately the same performance.